# Regex Quantifiers in Python (trying to match a group)

Tags: python, regex

My question is related to Metacharacters in Python :

`import re`

`string = 'Python 123'`

`print(re.search('(\d)+',string))` # It matches perfectly

```
<re.Match object; span=(7, 10), match='123'>
```

## But when it comes to (?) or (*) quantifiers :

```
print(re.search('(\d)?',string))

<re.Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
```

## Or

```
print(re.search('(\d)*',string))

<re.Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
```

My question is : -Why * and + don't match the digits in the string and shows span = (0,0) instead

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The second & third regex allows the empty string `''` to be matched.

`re.search` is merely returning the first match as documented: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search